# If $\mathbb{R}^3/\langle (1,0,1) \rangle $ then $(1,0,1)+\langle (1,0,1) \rangle = (0,0,0) + \langle (1,0,1) \rangle $ true or false

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $\mathbb{R}^3/\langle (1,0,1) \rangle $
And determine if $(1,0,1)+\langle (1,0,1) \rangle = (0,0,0) + \langle (1,0,1) \rangle $ is true or false
I think its true because $(0,0,0)=(1,0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3/\langle (1,0,1) \rangle $

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just looking for confirmation that you understand basic definitions.

Assuming you mean the usual (abelian) group structure on $\mathbb{R^3}$, then for any  abelian group $G$ with subgroup $H$, two elements (cosets) $\bar a$ and $\bar b$ in $G/H$ are the same if $a-b\in H$ and that is clearly true here, and I don't see any difference or issues if you are considering as real vector spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged linear algebra, I will assume, $\mathbb R^3$ to a vector space structure over the field $\mathbb R$.

I'll give a brief introduction to how I formally learned about quotient structures and cosets.

We consider a space $V$ with a subspace $W$. 
Define a relation on $V$ such that two vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ in $V$ are related if their difference $v_1-v_2$ is in $W$.

This relation is called modulo $W$. We say, $v_1\equiv v_2\pmod{W}\iff v_1-v_2\in W$.

It can be proven that this relation is an equivalence and hence, it induces a partition on $V$. This partition is the quotient structure $V/W$. It can be shown that $V/W$ forms a space under coset addition.

The equivalence classes under modulo $W$ are called cosets... It can be shown that for every $v\in V$, class of $v$ i.e., $[v]=v+W$.

In this case, $V=\mathbb R^3$ and $W=\langle(1,0,1)\rangle = \{(x,0,x)\ | \ x\in\mathbb R\}$.

You want to know if the cosets of modulo $W$ represented by $(1,0,1)$ and $(0,0,0)$ are identical or not.

Recall that two equivalence classes are identical if and only if their representatives are related. In this case, $(1,0,1)-(0,0,0)\in W$ so, $(1,0,1)\equiv (0,0,0)\pmod{W}$. Hence, the classes/cosets represented by them are identical i.e., $(1,0,1)+W=(0,0,0)+W$.